# Why Codeigniter Project Loading slow in online?

Tags: codeigniter, lazy-loading

My codeigniter project **loading very slow on online**  browser

But worked **fastly on localhost**.

My project is just like a media page.. 
It has google login. And just register login and upload post , youtube url upload ..

This is my home page controller

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class UserList extends CI_Controller
{
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->library('security');
    $this->load->library('tank_auth');
    $this->lang->load('tank_auth');
    // load database
    $this->load->database();
    // Load session library
    $this->load->library('session');
    echo $username = $this->input->get('username'); 
}

function index()
{
    if ($this->tank_auth->is_logged_in())   
    {
        $data['login_status'] = $this->tank_auth->is_logged_in();
        $data['userId'] = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();
        $data['username'] = $this->tank_auth->get_username();
        $id = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();
        $data['firstname'] = $this->tank_auth->get_firstname();
        $data['lastname'] = $this->tank_auth->get_lastname();
        $data['image'] = $this->tank_auth->get_image();
        //$data['gender'] = $this->tank_auth->get_gender();
        $data['userList'] = $this->db->or_not_like('id',$id)->get('users')->result();
        //$data['followers'] = $this->db->where('follower_id',$id)->get('users')->result();

        $pagename =  $this->db->where('id',$id)->get('users')->result();
        $data['loginuserpage'] = $pagename[0]->pagename;
        $this->load->view('header/login',$data);
        $this->load->view('pages/users',$data);
        $this->load->view('footer/footer');

    }
    else {
        $data['login_status'] = 0;
        $data['userList'] = $this->db->get('users')->result();
        $this->load->view('header/withoutLogin',$data);
        $this->load->view('pages/users',$data);
        $this->load->view('footer/footer');
        //redirect('/auth/login/');
    }
  }
```

I am using that if condition in all functions and pages

But still not start to upload , now itself its very slow

I dont know where is the problem occuring?..

Please kindly help me?.

Thanks in Advance,
**Shruthi.**

Comment: you should tell more about your project.

Comment: simple project only but having google login and getiing info from youtube url

Comment: Read [here](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) how to ask correct way, than add the code that is sufficient for debugging error.

Comment: check your server speed ram etc.. or upload the custom project to check the speed if the server speed is okay the check your loops and condition.

Comment: in localserver its worked fastly, so i think its not loop problem, Are you accept this.. ? or Is loop only problem.?

Answer (score 2):

First, please open debugging to see query times. Add this code in your core Controller (if exist) or any controller:

```
$this->output->enable_profiler(true);
```

Now, you can see query times under your web page. By the way, I think your problem is not about PHP but HTML. Probably your HTML loading slowly. If you can add an example view file, I'll be sure about that.

If your problem is front end (e.g. HTML, CSS, JS), you can minify them. Also you can stop to include unnecessary files in your HTML.

Edit: If you don't have any view, may be you have an authorization error for this Google thing. It can make the things slow.

Comment: i checked that query times. its zero.. But in my database connection i gave pconnect and db_debug FALSE.... Is this problem there?

Comment: if i upload only html code on server means its loading fastly.

Comment: controller execution time is 60.1205 in online